# How to record from amp to PC or Android device?

Tags: recording, cable

I have a Blackstar FLY 3 amp (this: https://blackstaramps.com/product/fly-3/), which provides a 3.5 mm output jack. This works great for headphones, but I've had no success getting this signal to any of my Android devices or laptops.

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- USB adapters. First, I think I mistakenly bought a USB adapter for speakers, so that failed. I then acquired this doodad: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07N355W9M?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details , but that was also of no use.
- Two different 3.5 mm male-male cables. One has two rings on the plugs at both ends, and the other has three. I plug one end into the amp, and the other into the Android or PC. Depending on which app and which input settings I use, I get either ambient mic sounds or silence on the line.

I suspect the problem has something to do with the cable. I guess the output is not sending on the "mic" channel, so my various devices don't see it.

Can somebody please suggest the right kind of cable for this purpose? Also, I'd love to know about a simple and effective (and preferably free) Android or Windows app that does this job. I'm using Audacity on the PC.

Comment: mobile phone 3.5mm inputs are typically 3-ring; PC ones are typically one. From [the manual](https://blackstaramps.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/fly-handbook.pdf), "This output emulates the tonal characteristics of a guitar speaker cabinet and
provides a natural valve overdrive tone for connection to a recording device or mixing desk, and for use with headphones. To make full use of the stereo reverb, use a stereo jack to two mono jacks splitter lead to feed two channels of the recording device or mixer. The output will also function into a mono guitar type lead."

Comment: In other words: your three-ring plug left one ring doing nothing in the amp, while your two-ring one was treated by the Android as output. Try a _one_-ring mono one, into the PC, or maybe a stereo-to-mono adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You need a USB sound card with line input. Don't worry too much about distinction between "mobile" and "desktop" models, Android phones are more or less computers in this regard. Plug the headphone/line output from the amplifier to the input on the sound card. Adjust amp volume and input sensitivity/gain if you have one so that the input does not max out. That's it.

Recording through the 3.5mm jack will not work, because it is designed for headset with high impedance microphone. Even if you manage to build a cable that has the right connections, the signal levels will be too far off for the result to sound good. This is also the reason why cables like this aren't sold.